# Search key and get value in dictionary - Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to match the values I saved in list "root" with the keys in the dictionary, so i can get the values. But I don't know how to do it. :/ Maybe someone has some inspiration for me. Thanks a lot!

Therefore I created a dictionary.

```
from turtle import clear
import pandas as pd 

df=pd.read_excel(r'path').fillna("@Null$tring").sort_values(by=['VP'])

SP = df['SP'].tolist()
VP = df['VP'].tolist()
root = []

#sSP = set(SP)
#sVP = set(VP)

root = [i for i in SP if i not in VP]

#index =root.index

print(root)
#print(index(root))

d = dict (zip(SP,VP))

for key in d.keys():
    if key == root[0]:
        print(key)
```

Comment: look into the `difference` method

Comment: So you need to create a list of values from dictionary `d` where the keys are items of list `root`? If so, [d[key] for key in root] will do the job.

Comment: Hi, i updated the explanation of my problem. I have values in a list, I need to know if these values are are as keys in the dictonary so i can get the respective values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm correctly understanding what you're trying to do, you should be able to make good use of [`pandas.Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) and [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html).

Here's an example with some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data.
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "AP" : ["foobar", "foo",  "bar",  "baz",  "foobar"],
    "SP" : ["qux",    "spam", "qux",  "ham",  "qux"],
    "VP" : ["spam",   "ham",  "spam", "eggs", "eggs"]
})

# Identifies values in SP not present in VP.
root = pd.Index(df1["SP"]).difference(pd.Index(df1["VP"]))

# Masks out data where the value of SP is not present in root,
# then selects only the SP and VP columns from the resulting
# DataFrame and resets the index. 
df2 = df1[df1["SP"].isin(root)][["SP", "VP"]].reset_index(drop = True)
```

To walk you through each step, in terms of output, given the sample data:

```
>>> df1
       AP    SP    VP
0  foobar   qux  spam
1     foo  spam   ham
2     bar   qux  spam
3     baz   ham  eggs
4  foobar   qux  eggs
```

`root` is taken as the difference between `df1["SP"]` and `df1["VP"]` cast as `pandas.Index` objects:

```
>>> pd.Index(df1["SP"])
Index(['qux', 'spam', 'qux', 'ham', 'qux'], dtype='object', name='SP')

>>> pd.Index(df1["VP"])
Index(['spam', 'ham', 'spam', 'eggs', 'eggs'], dtype='object', name='VP')

>>> pd.Index(df1["SP"]).difference(pd.Index(df1["VP"]))
Index(['qux'], dtype='object')
```

We then check which values of `df["SP"]` are present in `root` and use the resulting boolean `pandas.Series` as a mask for the `pandas.DataFrame`:

```
>>> df1["SP"].isin(root)
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: SP, dtype: bool

>>> df1[df1["SP"].isin(root)]
       AP   SP    VP
0  foobar  qux  spam
2     bar  qux  spam
4  foobar  qux  eggs
```

Finally, we can index only the two columns we're interested in and reset the index:

```
>>> df1[df1["SP"].isin(root)][["SP", "VP"]].reset_index(drop = True)
    SP    VP
0  qux  spam
1  qux  spam
2  qux  eggs
```

Comment: Thank you for this great explained example, this helps me so much to understand some methods and the way pandas works. I got one problem left. The data set contains varios dublicates in SP, so i get the error  **reindexing with a non-unique Index is deprecated and will raise in a future version.**. Is there some way to deal with this? I dont want to delete the duplicates, beacause i need to count them later.

Comment: Ah, got it. I just edited my answer to be more general. It should be able to handle duplicate values of SP now, and I've revised the sample data to reflect that. Let me know if that works any better.

Answer (score 1):

(I don't have enough reputation to comment so I post my comment as answer, apologies for that) Your for loop matches the keys with only first element of the list. Maybe this could help you out? ( I fixed my indentation and while loop sorry about that)

```
i = 0
while i <= len(d.keys()):
  
  for key in d.keys():
      if key == root[i]:
         print(key)
      i = i + 1
```